# Strapi Graphql Plugin Crashes Strapi Server

Tags: strapi

I just tried to install the graphql plugin for strapi (i.e., `strapi-plugin-graphql`).  When I tried to install it via the admin interface, I got the following error message:

> The restart takes longer than expected
>   The server should have restarted, please check your logs in the terminal

When I check my terminal, this is what I see:

```
[2019-12-27T07:47:12.612Z] debug GET /admin/plugins (5 ms) 200
[2019-12-27T07:47:15.882Z] info Installing graphql...
[2019-12-27T07:48:59.105Z] info File changed: C:\code\tutorials\react\Gatsby\strapi\startup-reporter\package.json[2019-12-27T07:48:59.279Z] debug POST /admin/plugins/install (103411 ms) 200
[2019-12-27T07:48:59.281Z] info The server is restarting

[2019-12-27T07:49:14.672Z] debug ⛔️ Server wasn't able to start properly.
[2019-12-27T07:49:14.674Z] error Error: Field "Query.news" can only be defined once.
    at assertValidSDL (C:\code\tutorials\react\Gatsby\strapi\startup-reporter\node_modules\graphql\validation\validate.js:108:11)
    at Object.buildASTSchema (C:\code\tutorials\react\Gatsby\strapi\startup-reporter\node_modules\graphql\utilities\buildASTSchema.js:71:34)
    at Object.buildSchemaFromTypeDefinitions (C:\code\tutorials\react\Gatsby\strapi\startup-reporter\node_modules\graphql-tools\dist\generate\buildSchemaFromTypeDefinitions.js:23:28)
    at makeExecutableSchema (C:\code\tutorials\react\Gatsby\strapi\startup-reporter\node_modules\graphql-tools\dist\makeExecutableSchema.js:26:29)
    at Object.generateSchema (C:\code\tutorials\react\Gatsby\strapi\startup-reporter\node_modules\strapi-plugin-graphql\services\Schema.js:300:22)
    at Object.initialize (C:\code\tutorials\react\Gatsby\strapi\startup-reporter\node_modules\strapi-plugin-graphql\hooks\graphql\index.js:59:50)
    at Promise.resolve.then (C:\code\tutorials\react\Gatsby\strapi\startup-reporter\node_modules\strapi\lib\hooks\index.js:37:28)
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! startup-reporter@0.1.0 dev: `strapi develop`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the startup-reporter@0.1.0 dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\moshe\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-12-27T07_49_14_697Z-debug.log
```

Any idea why I am getting this error message and how to fix it?

**UPDATE:**
I should note that I did a fresh install of strapi and then installed the graphql plugin -- and it installed properly.  It only didn't work with an installation that already had custom post types.  I don't know why that is -- and what I can do to install it with those custom post types.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the issue about this problem

https://github.com/strapi/strapi/issues/1198

Some words are not well managed for the `pluralize` version.

So the issue is due to that point.

There is currently nothing to do to fix it by your own.